# How do I know if I am mining in a pool?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining-pools, solo-mining

So I started mining from monero-wallet-cli using "start_mining 2".  When I enter "status", the output is as follows; "Refreshed 1254269/1254269, synced, daemon RPC v1.0".  Am I actually in a pool?  I have seen references to stale blocks if you are not mining in a pool, which leads me to believe that I may be.

Answer (score 4):

You are mining in a pool when you are running a pool miner. If you mine directly from the daemon or wallet, you are solo mining, not pool mining.

Solo mining, which is your case, means you will take a long time to find a block. However, when you do find one, you will get to keep the entire block reward (currently about 8 monero, I believe) instead of it being distributed among all pool miners and getting a pittance.

Note that solo mining is done by the deamon. Starting mining in the wallet merely instructs the daemon to do so. If you want to double check you are actually mining, run `status` in the daemon itself. If you restart the daemon, mining will be automatically off on restart, for instance, though you would not have told the wallet to stop mining.

Answer (score -1):

Go to pool web site and enter your address to field "Your Stats & Payment History"
Bellow that you will see your hash rate.
Probably you have to a wait a couple of minutes as pool show hash rate only from accepted shares.

Comment: while it is a good answer, the question was asked in the wrong place to begin with; hopefully the asker will re-post using a proper channel to keep our SE site tidy

Answer (score -3):

You can go to the pool's web site where you should be able to track your status and submitted shares.